# Using AAR file of my library which has dependency on other libraries

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using AAR file of my library which has a dependency on ExoStreamPlayer. My app is working good if I include the source code of the library as a module in android studio project but if I include the AAR file of the module/library then my app is throwing the following Exception at runtime.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ooyala.android.player.exoplayer.ExoStreamPlayer
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.player.ExoMoviePlayer.createStreamPlayer(ExoMoviePlayer.java:12)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.player.MoviePlayer.init(MoviePlayer.java:50)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.createAndInitPlayer(OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.java:107)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer.prepareContent(OoyalaPlayer.java:1469)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.processExitAdModes(OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.java:182)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.processAdModes(OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.java:162)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.startVideoWorkflow(OoyalaPlayerContextSwitcher.java:61)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer.onCurrentItemChangeComplete(OoyalaPlayer.java:697)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer.access$200(OoyalaPlayer.java:68)
>                                                                                    at com.ooyala.android.OoyalaPlayer$1$1.run(OoyalaPlayer.java:510)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja

**Update**
@ CommonsWare I think, I am using the second approach. You can see the exoplayer dependency in my library gradile.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0'

compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha3'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Please explain **exactly** how you "include the AAR file of the module/library". For example, you might provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are doing this.

Comment: @CommonsWare I followed the guidelines on https://developer.android.com which are 

"Add the compiled AAR (or JAR) file (the library must be already built):
1) Click File > New > New Module.
2) Click Import .JAR/.AAR Package then click Next.
3) Enter the location of the compiled AAR or JAR file then click Finish"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a bare JAR or AAR frequently does not work. In particular, it will not work if the JAR or AAR depends on other libraries, what are known as "transitive dependencies".

To get Gradle to automatically pull in transitive dependencies, Gradle needs to know what those dependencies are. There are two options for this:

1. The app module's `build.gradle` file has `compile project(':...')`, where `...` is the library module name
2. The app module's `build.gradle` file has `compile '...'`, where `...` is the artifact group/ID/version for the AAR as an artifact in an artifact repository

In the first case, Gradle knows the transitive dependencies because that information is in the library module's `build.gradle` file. In the second case, Gradle knows the transitive dependencies because the artifact repository should have that information along with the AAR (e.g., in the form of a Maven POM file).

Alternatively, you can use the bare AAR as you have, but the app (or other library) that is using that AAR will need to request all that AAR's transitive dependencies via its own `dependencies` roster.

Comment: @AdnanKhan: The library's `build.gradle` file only impacts builds of the library itself, including any POM that might be generated by that build as part of uploading the library to an artifact repository. In #2, I mean that the app needs to compile in the library using an artifact reference.

Comment: @ComonsWare: Thanks